# get first entries in rows of list?

Tags: r, list, indexing

I have a list, with 3 "columns":

```
test = list(1:100, 1:100,1:100)
```

How can I access the e.g. first 10 entries of each column?

```
test[c(1:10),]
```

doesn't work. I know it works for data.frames:

```
as.data.frame(test)[1:10,1:3]
```

How do I solve this with lists?

Edit: To get an answer more general:

How do I get the entries 15 to 20 in column 1 and 3? Here is what I do for data.frames:

```
as.data.frame(test)[c(15:20),c(1,3)]
```

It seems like the indexing differs a lot between data.frames and lists.

Comment: Hi, I notice you have *never* voted/accepted an answer. You might want to read the [**about**](http://stackoverflow.com/about) and [**FAQ**](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) sections of the website to help you get the most out of SO. If an answer does solve your problem you may want to *consider* upvoting and/or marking it as accepted to show the question has been answered, by ticking the little green check mark next to the suitable answer. You are **not** obliged to do this, but it helps keep the site clean of unanswered questions and rewards those who take the time to solve your problem.

Answer (score 12):

You can do it with functions `lapply()` and `head()`.

```
lapply(test,head,n=10)
[[1]]
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10

[[2]]
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10

[[3]]
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

If there will be less than `n=` values in list element then this show all values.

```
test = list(1:100, 1:100,1:5)
lapply(test,head,n=10)
[[1]]
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10

[[2]]
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10

[[3]]
[1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the return type you want, `lapply` or `sapply` will be useful. I'd use `[` to get the elements you want:

```
lapply( test , `[` , 1:10 )
[[1]]
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10

[[2]]
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10

[[3]]
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10

 sapply( test , `[` , 1:10 )
      [,1] [,2] [,3]
 [1,]    1    1    1
 [2,]    2    2    2
 [3,]    3    3    3
 [4,]    4    4    4
 [5,]    5    5    5
 [6,]    6    6    6
 [7,]    7    7    7
 [8,]    8    8    8
 [9,]    9    9    9
[10,]   10   10   10
```

Comment: your lapply() solution will produce NA values if there will be less than 10 values in list element and that could be misleading.

Comment: @DidzisElferts point taken, but that wasn't part of the original problem. If the OP comes back and says that's a requirement I'd use your solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Map` function which is helpful if you have two or more than two inputs in a function:

```
mytest<-Map(function(x) x[1:10], test)
> mytest
[[1]]
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10

[[2]]
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10

[[3]]
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

Comment: Simplifies to: `Map(head,test,10)`.